# CPanel cache issue

Tags: cpanel

I have made some changes in my site and updated them in the server via CPanel, but I can't see the changes affected. 
I have changed one pdf but still old pdf is displaying. Help me if anybody knows why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> dig +trace domain.com

And make sure that domain is pointed to the correct server IP (The one you have made changes)

There is no such things like cPanel cache. Otherwise try

> telnet server_IP 25

make sure that its points to the correct server IP.

If the domain points to the correct server where you have made changes, then you need to investigate based on the script or code .check whether the pdf file uploaded correctly

Answer (score 0):

Some its happens to me too but even though we upload it corrected its our browser cache which still shows the old pages and does not reflect the new changes. Most of time i do check it in private browser or via proxy urls :D